# Intellisense in notepad++

Tags: firefox, notepad++, intellisense

It is possible configure notepad++ to the Intellisense show options about firefox os api?

e.g. To can see all methods

```
var battery = navigation.battery;
battery.level;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but Notepad++ (current releases) have a form of this known as AutoComplete - go to **Settings > Preferences > Auto-completion** and tick the *enable auto-completion for each input** button.

As for the Firefox OS API specifically, I don't know if that works. But I know you can achieve the intellisense effect with languages themselves, anyway.

Keep in mind the differences between "Function Completion" and "Word completion" inside auto-complete: *Function Completion* uses external cues to tell you exactly what you're trying to write in, as it autocompletes functions from an API.

*Word completion* meanwhile may be more helpful in your case; If Firefox OS API can't be worked into NPP, you can at least auto-complete functions that you've already written into your script, as Word completion scans your document and suggests words that already exist; It's sort of useful as a text expansion engine.

I hope I've been of help; Best of luck to you.